# Upload Django app and set database correctly

Tags: django, git, postgresql, openshift, django-settings

Hi I want to upload my django app to openshift rhc with git. After push and refresh the mainpage is displayed, however everything which needs user instance is not working.

My error is:

```
'Ident authentication failed for user "admin"'

...py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in _cursor, line 177
```

I think database is not connected properly:

in my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'MY_APP_NAME',
    'USER': 'admin',
    'PASSWORD': 'MY_PASSWORD',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

I didn't do manage.py syncdb, I do not know how to do it. Maybe that is the problem, because superuser is not created ?

What about path to db? On my computer settings.py looks a litle bit different:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '//home//pachucx//Project//db//sqlite3.db',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

Everything worked fine on the computer.

The difference is that in NAME I am using path to the DB file, where on serwer side I use only name of it. Should I add extension .db, or maybe there is need to add a path I dont know.
Or maybe the problem will be solved just by manage.py syncdb? If it is so, tell me how to do it properly e.g with git

Many thanks.

Comment: Why should doing syncdb be any different on the server? And why would you think it would have anything to do with git?

Comment: How can I make syncdb on the server? I did not do it at all.

Comment: You haven't explained why you think it would be any different! Just do `./manage.py syncdb`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error that is occurring because of your attempt to access the database that is either not created, or you have invalid username and password credentials in your settings file.

1. Make sure you configure all the settings correctly. - Check your `host`, db `username` and `password` as well as the `port` - it could be different from your local box.
2. In order to sync the database you need to navigate in SSH to your project root and locate the `manage.py` file. Once you have that run the following command:

   python manage.py syncdb

This will either:

1. Create all the tables,
2. Give you a nasty error saying your settings for your database are not correct, this is a great error to get as you know you need to look into the settings again and correct the problem.

To test whether or not your server can be initiated run the following command in SSH again

```
python manage.py runserver
```

1. If successful, this will give you a local test environment and should spit out a url to test. Should be `localhost:8000` or something similar.
2. If fails, this will let you know if you have models improperly configured, mainly your settings, or url file it will give an error on so you can double check everything is up.

As for using the database that is on your machine on a machine outside of your network I advise to not do that. Go and create the database on the box you have, and make notes of the host, username, password, database name etc, and go back to start of this answer.

All the best,